# DELPHI, How can I receive the name of the form that is on top

Tags: forms, delphi, hook

I have a data module where I added a KeyHookProc. This data module is created before all forms and the hook should catch the name of the form that is on top of the application.
I've tried both Screen.ActiveForm and Screen.FocusedForm but both points to the applications Main-form.
The main form is of course not closed but I wouldn't say it's active or focused. The active/focused should be the form that I opened last teh one that I currently working in.
But, apparently not.
Is there another way to find the form that is on top?

Comment: You can use `GetWindow` passing `GW_HWNDFIRST` and `GW_HWNDNEXT` to enum top level windows in Z order.

Comment: Screen.ActiveForm should work fine. If you provide code to reproduce, then maybe someone will help you.

Comment: I wonder what's the distinction between focused and active form. Docs: *"FocusedForm: Provides a reference to the form that has focus."* vs. *"ActiveForm: Indicates which form currently has focus."*

Comment: `FocusedForm` is the `TForm` that contains the `FocusedControl` who has the current input focus. `ActiveForm` is the active `TForm` at the top of the Z-order, and may or may not have the `FocusedControl` in it.

Comment: I have done a stupid mistake, I catched the formobject from screen.ActiveForm inside it's create-constructor and of course that will not work. I'm sorry bothering you with this. Thank's anyway.